# How do the Purple Boxes work?

Tags: duck-game

I've seen the purple boxes in a few maps, and I know that it stores what item you have in your hand.  But I have a couple questions:

- **How long** does it store the item?
- If **another player** puts a different item in, does it change it for
  you? Or will it give you the same item you put in?
- Does the box save **across matches**?

Me, my brother, and a couple of my friends were wondering about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How long does it store the item?
>
> Does the box save across matches?

It persists through the entire session. It also persists across sessions if the host decides to play another round while displaying the trophy board (I don't know what happens if you go back to the lobby first). It doesn't persist if you disconnect.

> If another player puts a different item in, does it change it for you? Or will it give you the same item you put in?

The save block is local to your player only; items that opponents save do not affect the item you have saved.